# NoClassDefFoundException in N-tier application

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am building a project for a class that I am taking, and it consists of 4 modules

```
-impl (business logic/dao access)
-ejb  (encapsulates business logic and provides access to it via a remote interface)
-war (web tier)
-ear (contains the war and ejb modules)
```

One utility class that I have inside the impl is able to populate an H2 database. It does this by running an ingestor that reads in an processes an xml file that resides in a maven repository, using various dao classes/methods to ingest the data:

```
String fileName = "xml/proj-data.xml";
        InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
```

When I run the ingestor through a unit test, it runs fine, but when I have everything layered, I get the NoClassDefFoundException on xml/proj-data.xml

So the basic outline that I have is:

```
-the war has dependencies on the impl and ejb modules
-the ejb has dependency on the impl module
-the ear has dependency on the impl, ejb, and war
```

This is a maven project. When I deploy the EAR to the server, the start page for the war is displayed (as I expect).

-The html page has a button that when pressed, does a post to a servlet
-The servlet has an ejb injected into it that it calls (via its remote interface).
-The ejb method makes a call back to the populate method in the impl, and thats when the exception happens, and I get a webpage back showing the exception.

Do I need to declare that repository in the WAR pom file as well?

Comment: 'an xml file that resides in a maven repository,' Your code doesn't look like it is reading from a Maven repository.

Comment: the xml file is not on my local machine, it gets read in from the classpath. The inputstream gets passed in as an argument to my ingestor.

Answer (score 0):

In typing the question, I think I know what the problem may be. The repository that the xml file resides in is declared in the root pom for the project(the impl parent), NOT the pom for the impl module. Since the impl is the module that gets packaged with the EAR, I may need to declare the repository in the impl pom file as well.